# Cloud Firestore 'Oops, collections failed to load!'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to play around with the new Cloud Firestore but when I choose the firestore dropdown the datapanel says: 'Oops, collections failed to load!'

Is this attempting to import my existing realtimeDB into and failing or some other reason?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not.

You might see this error if the Cloud Firestore API is not enabled: Check on the [Cloud Firestore API page](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/firestore.googleapis.com?project=_) after selecting your project name.

You might also see this if App Engine is disabled, since we rely upon some common infrastructure: Check on the [App Engine Settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings?project=_) page to ensure it's not disabled after for your project.

Comment: Thanks, in this instance I had disabled AppEngine.

Comment: No problem - glad it's sorted out!

Comment: Hi Dan, I also have a disabled App Engine because I don't know how to 'clear' it if that's the right word (it is an old server we no longer use). I don't really want to turn it back on because it would just sit there doing nothing. Is there a way to return app engine to some sort of default? It won't let me delete the instance because it's the default, hence the problem. Thanks

Comment: When I enabled app engine, will it cost additional money for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm seeing the same error on my Firefox browser but it's working well on Chrome!

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue and I solved it by [cloud firestore API](https://console.cloud.google.com/) page and select a project. Then click enable the firestore API.

[image]